# "We can really do what [we were]/[we've been] pretending to do"

Tags: sentence-choice, past-vs-past-perfect

Which one is right out of the following?

> We can really do what we were pretending to do
>
> We can really do what we've been pretending to do

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but not entirely natural in writing (at least to me, a British English speaker).

They would be natural in speech, with the right emphasis:

> We can really **do** what we were **pretending** to do
>   We can really **do** what we've been **pretending** to do

They are different in meaning. The first is where you pretended some time in the past, but are not pretending now. The that you pretended over some period in the past, and either stopped very recently or are still pretending.

For more natural version in writing, I would go for:

> We can actually do what we were (only) pretending to do
>   We can actually do what we've (only) been pretending to do

The *only* is optional.

You can also do it with other tenses/moods/aspects:

> We can actually do what we were only going to pretend to do
>   We can actually do what we had only pretended to do
>   We would actually do what we could only have pretended to do

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. The long form of both would be

We can actually do what we were previously only pretending to do.

We can actually do what we have previously only been pretending to do.

Comment: But we can not use have been with previously.  Or can we?  I thought have been is used it lately/recently

Comment: I believe lately or recently would be more a more formal way of saying it, however they all still carry the same meaning

Comment: @user51335 "Have previously" is something of a set phrase that can put what looks like the present perfect further back in the past, or simply emphasises that it is in the past. So "have previously been", whether used with a participle/gerund or an adjective, puts that state definitely in the past, reducing the possibility of it being something that still pertains.